# How do I parse more than one parameters from the response in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, json

Currently, I am using JSON Path Extractor as my POST PROCESSOR to parse parameters from response body.
Suppose say I have to parse two parameters from response 'AuthenticationToken' as well as 'userId'.

Do I have to add two 'JSON Path extractor' or what? If this is the solution then how should I parse if there are many parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it in one JSON Path Extractor.

I don't have access to JMeter right now, but here's an [example](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter) on the linked page in the "Selecting Multiple Values with One Expression" section.

[Additional reference](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html#e2) on building JSONPaths.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Regular Expression](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) Extractor.

For example you want to get the token from

```
 data="user" token="asd23453453sad">
```

A regular expression would be

```
  data="user" token="(.+?)">
```

Answer (score 1):

As Ravana said, you can do this with the [built in JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor). You have to specify the same number of variable names as JSON Path Expressions. The names and expressions have to be separated by semicolons.

So, if you have a JSON structure like

```
{
 "userId": 23,
 "AuthenticationToken": "abc-123"
}
```

and want to extract those into the JMeter variables `user_id` and `token`, you would fill in `variable names` with

```
user_id;token
```

then you fill in `JSON Path expressions` with

```
$.userId;$.AuthenticationToken
```

and last you have to give default values for all your expected variables. So you fill in `Default Values` with something like

```
-1;"invalid token"
```